# root is logged in even though I disabled the root login

Tags: vps

I got a new unmanaged vps (centos7) a few days ago. I took care of all the initial stuff: disabled root login, set up a firewall, etc...

And now I was installing apache, php, mysql and at one point I just wanted to check the logged users, so I typed who -s and i got:

root     hvc0         2014-12-27 00:04

me       pts/0        2014-12-29 01:37 (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) <--- this is me

And i was surprised to see root is logged in for 2 days. Is this normal or is it someone that has broken into my vps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hvc0 is the xen serial console, i.e. the fake serial-like console emulating an old-school directly-attached serial console you'd have on a physical server.  It depends on your VPS provider whether or not they expose that console to you, perhaps via a web interface.  If they do, have a look there and you'll find root logged in, and can logout.  If that wasn't you, and the history looks odd, then perhaps someone has managed to log in to the web interface, get to the console, and guess the root password (unlikely, but a bad thing; you may as well consider the server compromised and in need of a rebuild, if this is the case)

It's also *possibly* the VPS hosting provider, but as you say "unmanaged VPS", they shouldn't even have the root password.

Comment: Thanks, it's probably not an attacker by looking at the logs. Can you tell me how to log as root into hcv0 so i can log it out? I have no idea.

Comment: Your VPS provider may expose the console through a web interface somewhere.  Are you able to tell us which provider that is?

Comment: My VPS provider is site5.

Comment: http://kb.site5.com/types/unmanaged-vps/unmanaged-vps-how-to-access-the-console/